# Duda con expresión regular para validar PIN de 4 o 6 digitos

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una expresión regular en javascript que no entiendo cual es la función de los paréntesis, por que cuando los quito la expresión regular ya no funciona y acepta 4 dígitos o mas

```
/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/g
```

Comment: puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión ^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{4}|.{6})$ podes revisarla en https://regexr.com/

Comment: A eso se le llama grupo de captura, revisa en el wiki que pasé, allí hay una buena explicación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los paréntesis `()` sirven para agrupar y adicionalmente para capturar (capturar significa poder recuperar más adelante el trozo que se ha encontrado dentro de los paréntesis).

Los paréntesis sin captura `(?:)` sirven solamente para agrupar.

En tu expresión regular, el uso de paréntesis (bastaría paréntesis sin captura) es necesario porque al quitarlos te queda lo siguiente:

```
^\d{4}|\d{6}$
```

Como sabrás, `|` sirve para separar dos expresiones. Al quitar los paréntesis, el inicio de línea `^` forma parte de la expresión de la izquierda, mientras que el fin de línea `$` forma parte de la expresión de la derecha. Entonces, esa expresión significa:

> Empieza por 4 números **o** Termina con 6 números

Lo cual te permite poner números de más de 6 dígitos o incluso letras siempre que termine con 6 dígitos o los 4 primeros sean dígitos.

Así que realmente lo que quieres es tener un inicio y fin para cada parte de la expresión, de ahí que utilizaras paréntesis para agrupar las dos opciones.

Si no quisieras utilizar paréntesis, una expresión equivalente hubiera sido:

```
^\d{4}$|^\d{6}$
```

Es decir, agregamos `^` y `$` a ambos lados.

Otra opción podría haber sido:

```
^\d{4}(?:\d\d)?$
```

Es decir: Inicio de la cadena, 4 números, y luego opcionalmente `?` dos números. Nota que utilizo un grupo para agrupar los dos números juntos y que así el `?` afecte a ambos a la vez. De esta manera o aparecen los dos números o no aparece ninguno.

**NOTA**

Si no se pretende *capturar* lo que hay dentro de los paréntesis, entonces se considera más adecuado utilizar paréntesis **sin** captura. Por ejemplo:

```
^(?:\d{4}|\d{6})$
```